# On partial integration of $W^{1,p}_0(U)$ functions and boundary terms.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

If $\varphi$ is a testfunction with compact support in $U$ then for for example $f \in W^{1,p}(U)$, where $U$ is open.

We have $\int\limits_U \varphi^\prime f= - \int_U\limits f^\prime \varphi $

Sometimes I would like to have

$\int\limits_U \varphi^\prime f= - \int_U\limits f^\prime \varphi $

where this time $\varphi  \in W^{1,p}_0(U)$.

Does that actually hold and why?

I think we do not have in generall that $\varphi\vert_{\partial U}=0$ for $\varphi  \in W^{1,p}_0(U)$.

I would like to have that at least in the case where $U$ is bounded with boundary in $C^1$.

Comment: All functions on $W_0^{1,p}$ are limit of sequence of testfunctions on the norm of $W^{1,p}$. And it seems that the map $\phi\to\int f^\prime \phi$ is a continuous one

Comment: @Jacaré great advise. If $p=2$ we could apply Cauchy Schwarz but if $p\neq 2$ Hölder is only possible if $f^\prime$ is in $L^q$ but this does not have to be, no?

Comment: And if you use dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @MackeyTopology The identity $\int_{U}\phi' f = -\int_{U}\phi f'$ holds for $\phi \in W_0^{1, q}$ since both sides are continuous in $\phi$ with respect to the $W^{1, q}$ norm, and both agree on the dense subspace $C_c^{\infty}(U)$ of $W_0^{1, q}(U)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us prove for the case where $p\geq 2$ and $U$ is an open and bounded set.

Let $\phi\in W_0^{1,p}$. By definition, there exist a sequence of test functions $\phi_n$ such that $\phi_n\to\phi$ on $W^{1,p}$. This means that both $\phi_n^\prime\to\phi^\prime$ ,$\phi_n\to\phi$ on $L^p$. [By the Inverse Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834822/inverse-of-the-dominated-convergence-theorem) There is a subsequence $(k_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\phi_{k_i}(x)\to\phi(x)$ and $\phi^\prime_{k_i}(x)\to\phi^\prime(x)$ almost everywhere and functions $g_1$, $g_2$ in $L^p$ such that $|\phi_{k_i}(x)|\leq g_1(x)$ and $|\phi^\prime_{k_i}(x)|\leq g_2(x)$ a.e. on $U$. Therefore  $|f^\prime(x)\phi_{k_i}(x)|\leq |f^\prime(x)|g_1(x)$ and $|f(x)\phi^\prime_{k_i}(x)|\leq |f(x)|g_2(x)$. Since $p\geq 2$ [$fg_2,f^\prime g _1\in L^{p/2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2346068/product-of-lp-functions-is-in-lp-2) and since $U$ is bounded, $|f|g_2,|f^\prime| g_1\in L ^1$. So applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem we get the desired result.